# How to reset Primary key counter in SQFLITE Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, sqflite

I am creating an android application using flutter and I am using `SQFLITE` for storing user data locally. But I am facing an issue while deleting all the rows from table.

The issue is when I try to delete all the rows from table by using

```
db.delete("table name");
```

function all the rows are deleted but the `PRIMARY KEY` counter is not reset.

can Anyone help me out to reset the `PRIMARY KEY` counter.

Thank you In Advance!

Comment: delete from your_table;    
delete from sqlite_sequence where name='your_table';